# JavaScript copy selection from image to image

Tags: javascript

I load a picture and draw it on canvas. With the mouse I can draw on the picture. Now I want to copy a defined part of an another picture to the same part of the shown picture. I thought I can copy the pixels from img2 to img1. Another idea is to place the pictures on top of the other (img1 oder img2) and cut an area from img1.

I don't know what is a possible way.

My try:

```
function loadPic() {
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('can').getContext('2d');  
img = new Image();
img2 = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    ctx2.drawImage(img,0,0); 
}

img.src = 'Haut vorne m.bmp';
img2.src = 'Muskeln vorne m.bmp';
```

}

And the copy:

```
var g = img2.getImageData(262, 157, 200, 200);
ctx.putImageData(g, 55, 170);
```

I get an error: img2.getImageData is not a function

Can anybody help ?

Thank you !

Comment: I think you need to apply the `getImageData()` call to a canvas, instead of to the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

`getImageData()` is a function of canvas, not of Image. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

Replace `img2.getImageData(...)` with `ctx.getImageData(...)` or `ctx2` if that's what you have.

Comment: But I have only one image on canvas. I need to copy from an image to canvas. I tryed

var g = ctx.getImageData(262, 157, 200, 200);
ctx.putImageData(g, 55, 170);

I get an error:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Or can I make a second canvas with is invisible and copy from there to the original canvas ?